# Play Framework 2.6.x Execute code after Evolutions applied

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Is there a way to execute code after evolutions have been applied in the play framework without using the global settings?  It seems like this could be done with dependency injection but I don't have a clue how to start.

Comment: I didn't understand your question but whenever application comes up evolutions are the first thing which gets applied.

Comment: You are right!  I was confused because I have an println statement that prints out to the console before evolutions are ran but after running the evolution my data is in the database.